# Running a scrapy app in Heroku throws error

Tags: python, heroku, scrapy

Trying to run a Scrapy app in Heroku using

```
heroku run scrapy crawl spider
```

returns

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 76, in wrapper
ffi.def_extern(name=name, **kwargs)(func)
AttributeError: 'CompiledFFI' object has no attribute 'def_extern'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means the wrong version of cffi is installed. Try upgrading it to the latest version (or at least 1.4+) and this problem should go away.